# Pry-debug not stepping in the right method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, pry

I'm using [Searchkick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick) gem. I'm stepping in its methods to get something I need. At some point I find this code:

```
[1] pry(#<Searchkick::Query>)> s

From: /Users/borjagvo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/searchkick-1.3.4/lib/searchkick/query.rb @ line 71 Searchkick::Query#execute:

    67: def execute
    68:   @execute ||= begin
    69:     begin
 => 70:       response = execute_search
    71:       if @misspellings_below && response["hits"]["total"] < @misspellings_below
    72:         prepare
    73:         response = execute_search
    74:       end
    75:     rescue => e # TODO rescue type
    76:       handle_error(e)
    77:     end
    78:     handle_response(response)
    79:   end
    80: end
```

If a step into `execute_search` it will take me to `searchkick-1.3.4/lib/searchkick/logging.rb`, where there's a `execute_search` definition:

```
From: /Users/borjagvo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/searchkick-1.3.4/lib/searchkick/logging.rb @ line 12 Searchkick::QueryWithInstrumentation#execute_search:

     6: def execute_search
     7:   name = searchkick_klass ? "#{searchkick_klass.name} Search" : "Search"
     8:   event = {
     9:     name: name,
    10:     query: params
    11:   }
 => 12:   ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument("search.searchkick", event) do
    13:     super
    14:   end
    15: end
```

However, there another definition right in the same file where `execute_search` is called (`searchkick-1.3.4/lib/searchkick/query.rb`). That's the method actually being called, and not the other in `logging.rb`. Why `pry-debugger` takes me to the wrong definition? Is it a bug or is there something I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `searchkick-1.3.4/lib/searchkick/logging.rb` in line 179,

```
Searchkick::Index.send(:prepend, Searchkick::IndexWithInstrumentation)
```

This statement makes `Searchkick::IndexWithInstrumentation#execute_search` take precedence on the `Searchkick::Index#execute_search`.